# Enforcing argument and return documentation in the docstring

Tags: python, google-style-guide, yapf

I'm trying to add a linter to a repo that would enforce docstring documentation of arguments and return values for functions and methods, as described in the [Google Python Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/pyguide.html#383-functions-and-methods).

In general, I want to enforce the following docstring content:

```py
def blah(n: int) -> int:
    """
    Args:
        n: a number
    
    Returns:
        The number plus 1
    """
    return n+1
```

I looked into [YAPF](https://github.com/google/yapf/), Google's own Python formatting tool, but could not find a configuration argument and return values. A broader search on this subject did not yield anything.

How can I enforce argument and return value documentation in a docstring using a linter?

Comment: https://github.com/PyCQA/pydocstyle?

Comment: Care to add it as an answer @jonrsharpe?